# DirectMessage authentication in Twitter4j API

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am working with a twitter client project which is using the `Twitter4j` API. My program is able to read tweets from the timeline, see followers and follower list, but whenever I want to access `DirectMessage` it shows

```
errors:code:93-message:This application is not allowed to
access or delete your direct messages
```

I have following
authentication-

```
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Static.CONSUMER_KEY,Static.CONSUMER_SECRET);
 AccessToken accessToken = Static.CURRENT_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN;
 twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
 twitter = Static.CURRENT_TWITTER;
```

Any idea what causes the error above?

Answer (score 1):

When access directmessage using twitter4j, an error shows "unable to parse '3577866941' as integer".I have set the value of ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET which I got from dev.twitter but it crashes when the application runs.I use twitter4j-core-2.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar as library.The code is given bellow.

```
public ResponseList<DirectMessage> dmList=null;
public static AccessToken token = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESSTOKEN_SECRET);
TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
twitter = factory.getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token); 
try {
    dmList = twitter.getDirectMessages(new Paging(1,15));
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need "Read, Write and Direct Messages" permission to read / delete direct messages.
Make sure that your application is in the appropriate role at https://dev.twitter.com/apps .

Comment: Thank you Yusuke.Can you share twitter4j-core-2.2.4-SNAPSHOT-0701.jar file?